# How to update values in QWeb template in odoo dynamically?

Tags: odoo, qweb, odoo-13

I'm trying to develop barcode scanning module to make inventory transfers using barcode scanner.
I made QWeb template and render it with `this.$el.html` method and I can see that view rendered appropriately. The problem is that values I pass to the template is not updating with client actions. How do I make them dynamically changed when I change them in js script? Code goes here:

barcode-scanner.js

```js
odoo.define('stock.barcode_scanner', function(require) {
    'use sctrict';

    var AbstractAction = require('web.AbstractAction');
    var core = require('web.core');
    var QWeb = core.qweb;
    var _t = core._t;

    var BarcodeAction = AbstractAction.extend({

        start: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.$el.html(QWeb.render("BarcodeHandlerView", {widget: self}));
            core.bus.on('barcode_scanned', this, this._onBarcodeScanned);

            return this._super();
        },

        destroy: function () {
            core.bus.off('barcode_scanned', this, this._onBarcodeScanned);
            this._super();
        },

        _onBarcodeScanned: function(barcode) {
            var self = this;
            this._rpc({
                    model: 'stock.barcode.handler',
                    method: 'product_scan',
                    args: [barcode, ],
                })
                .then(function (result) {
                    if (result.action) {
                        var action = result.action;
                        if (action.type === 'source_location_set') {
                            self.sourceLocation = action.value;
                        } else if (action.type === 'product_added') {
                            if (self.productsList === undefined) {
                                self.productsList = [];
                            }
                            self.productsList.push(action.value);
                        } else if (action.type === 'destination_location_set') {
                            self.destionationLocation = action.value;
                        } else if (action.type === 'validation') {
                            self.sourceLocation = undefined;
                            self.productsList = undefined;
                            self.destinationLocation = undefined;
                        }
                    }
                    if (result.warning) {
                        self.do_warn(result.warning);
                    }
                });
        },
    });

    core.action_registry.add('stock_barcode_scanner', BarcodeAction);

    return {
        BarcodeAction: BarcodeAction,
    };
});
```

transfers.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<template id="theme.tp_remove_button"> 
    <t t-name="BarcodeHandlerView">
        <div>Source Location: <t t-esc="widget.sourceLocation"/></div>
        <div>Destination Location: <t t-esc="widget.destinationLocation"/></div>
    </t>
</template>
```

I am sure that everything is set properly at `__manifest__.py` - I can see the view, but client action doesn't trigger page update - and client actions are running when I trigger them - I can see my warnings I return from python function. What am I doing wrong? Should I use some other approach to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must to create an action to catch the event when your element change.

```
odoo.define('stock.barcode_scanner', function(require) {
    'use sctrict';

     var AbstractAction = require('web.AbstractAction');
     var core = require('web.core');
     var QWeb = core.qweb;
     var _t = core._t;

     var BarcodeAction = AbstractAction.extend({

     // ***** Add this to catch events on your template
     events: {
        'change #destination-location': '_onBarcodeScanned',
     },

     start: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.$el.html(QWeb.render("BarcodeHandlerView", {widget: self}));
        core.bus.on('barcode_scanned', this, this._onBarcodeScanned);

        return this._super();
     },

     destroy: function () {
        core.bus.off('barcode_scanned', this, this._onBarcodeScanned);
        this._super();
     },

     action_change_destination: function (newLocation = null) {
        if(newLocation  === null){
            return null;
        }else{
            let self = this;
            console.log("My new awesome destination changing....");
            self.destinationLocation = newLocation;
            $("#detination-location").html(self.destinationLocation);
        } 
     },
     _onBarcodeScanned: function(barcode) {
         var self = this;
         this._rpc({
                model: 'stock.barcode.handler',
                method: 'product_scan',
                args: [barcode, ],
            })
            .then(function (result) {
                if (result.action) {
                    var action = result.action;
                    if (action.type === 'source_location_set') {
                        self.sourceLocation = action.value;
                    } else if (action.type === 'product_added') {
                        if (self.productsList === undefined) {
                            self.productsList = [];
                        }
                        self.productsList.push(action.value);
                    } else if (action.type === 'destination_location_set') {
                        self.destionationLocation = action.value;
                        // ****** GO AND CHANGE YOUR DESTINATION  *****
                        self.action_change_destination(self.destionationLocation);
                    } else if (action.type === 'validation') {
                        self.sourceLocation = undefined;
                        self.productsList = undefined;
                        self.destinationLocation = undefined;
                    }
                }
                if (result.warning) {
                    self.do_warn(result.warning);
                }
            });
    },
    });

    core.action_registry.add('stock_barcode_scanner', BarcodeAction);

   return {
       BarcodeAction: BarcodeAction,
   };
});
```

And in your view should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<template id="theme.tp_remove_button"> 
<t t-name="BarcodeHandlerView">
       <div>Source Location: <t t-esc="widget.sourceLocation"/></div>
       <div>Destination Location: <span id="destination-location" /></div>
   </t>
</template>
```

Comment: thanks a lot!
I've thought there are some ways to do it using QWeb, but your solution fits quite well